# A sequência não contém elementos

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Esse é o erro que dá.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Abaixo a minha expressão que gerou o erro:

```
if (refeicoes != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < refeicoes.Length; i++) {
        lista.Add(pesquisaHotel.Where(x => x.SubOfferGroups.Select(a => a.AnswerOffersList[0].IncludesItems).Contains(refeicoes[i])).Select(a=> a.ProductId).First());
        lista.Add(pesquisaHotel.Where(x => x.SubOfferGroups.Select(a => a.AnswerOffersList[0].IncludesFoodPlans).Contains(refeicoes[i])).Select(a => a.ProductId).First());
    }

    pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => lista.Contains(x.ProductId)).ToArray();
}
```

O erro aparece em cima da linha `refeicoes`. Esse array tem um valor, que nesse caso é: `"Breakfast for 2"`. Alguém tem uma dica para resolver esse pepino?

Pessoal, descobri que o loop acima está errado. Não pode ser em cima de refeicoes, mas em cima de pesquisaHotel, pois refeicoes sempre virá com um registro. Ele é montado com um clique em cima do checkbox. Refiz o loop, trocando refeicoes por pesquisaHotel. Só fiz isso e agora dá o erro assim. Quando i == 0, ele adiciona na lista. mas quando i é maior que zero, aí dá pau, dizendo "Índice fora dos limites". Como eu resolvo isso? Abaixo o novo código. Lembrando que nesse exemplo, refeicoes tem apenas um registro.

```
if (refeicoes != null)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < pesquisaHotel.Length; i++)
    {
        lista.Add(pesquisaHotel.Where(x => x.SubOfferGroups.Select(a => a.AnswerOffersList[0].IncludesFoodPlans).Contains(refeicoes[i])).Select(a => a.ProductId).FirstOrDefault());
        lista.Add(pesquisaHotel.Where(x => x.SubOfferGroups.Select(a => a.AnswerOffersList[0].IncludesItems).Contains(refeicoes[i])).Select(a => a.ProductId).FirstOrDefault());
    }

    pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => lista.Contains(x.ProductId)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Essa variavel "refeicoes" é o que? Um array?

Comment: Sim, um array de strings

Comment: Então, eu procuro o valor contido nesse array em dois campos e adiciono na lista o produto pelo ID dele

Comment: Se é um array então, a verificação tem que ser feita assim: if(refeicoes[indice] != null){...}

Comment: É obvio que o novo código vai dar erro. Se a variável `refeicoes` é um array que tem 1 elemento, então o único índice possível a ser usado é o `0`, qualquer índice maior que 0 vai dar exceção.

Answer (score 11):

Esse erro acontece na chamada do método `First()` do Linq, quando a coleção na qual você o chama está vazia.

Você tem duas opções:

- Rever o trecho que diz `Select(a=> a.ProductId).First()` - essa seleção não retorna nenhum item. Talvez você precise rever toda a lógica até chegar a este ponto. É bastante recomendável quebrar seu código em mais passos, pois assim você pode isolar melhor em qual ponto suas consultas não retornam o que você espera;
- Utilizar o método [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ao invés do `First()`. Dessa forma, ao invés de disparar uma exceção, você terá uma referência nula. Daí você pode tratar como lhe for mais conveniente.

Comment: Jóia Renan, acho ser isso mesmo. O que acontece vi agora. Veja que fiz dois add, por que? Às vezes IncludesItems ora vem vazio e ora não. E o mesmo para IncludesFoodsPlans, pois ambos tem a mesma informação(coisa de português) e nesse meu exemplo calhou do primeiro, In cludesItems estar vazio. Vou trocar para FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 0):

Foi resolvido assim:

```
string[] produtoId ;

if (refeicoes != null)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < refeicoes.Length; i++)
                {
                    produtoId = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => x.SubOfferGroups.Select(a => a.AnswerOffersList[0].IncludesFoodPlans).Contains(refeicoes[i])).Select(a => a.ProductId).ToArray();

                    for (int x = 0; x < produtoId.Length; x++)
                    {
                        lista.Add(produtoId[x]);
                    }

                    produtoId = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => x.SubOfferGroups.Select(a => a.AnswerOffersList[0].IncludesItems).Contains(refeicoes[i])).Select(a => a.ProductId).ToArray();

                    for (int x = 0; x < produtoId.Length; x++)
                    {
                        lista.Add(produtoId[x]);
                    }

                }


                pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => lista.Contains(x.ProductId)).ToArray();
            }
```

Gostaria de votar na resposta do Renan, como eu faço? Recebi um email onde os moderas daqui me fizeram algumas advertências. Recebi as advertências como algo positivo sim. Eu aqui na empresa, não consigo ler as regras do forum e confesso estou meio perdido. É um forum bem diferente dos demais. Das advertências que eu recebi, apenas uma não posso concordar, que foi ser mais claros nas perguntas. Essa tal "clareza" é puramente relativa. Perguntamos de uma forma que entendemos. Mas fora isso, vou prestar mais atenção em tudo que eu postar, mas com ressalvas. Ainda não me familiarizei com o forum, mas nesse feriado próximo, irei ler as regras, faqs e etc, para não cometer erros, ou pelo menos minimizá-los. Estou escrevendo isso aqui, porque não pude responder no email que me enviaram e não gosto de receber email e não poder responder. Acho isso errado. Mas espero colaborar para melhoria desse forum e o que depender de mim, será feito, com certeza.

Comment: Em baixo do triangulo com um número(inicialmente zero) está o botão que `aceita` a resposta.

Comment: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, Miguel, de boa.

Comment: @pnet Isso não foi uma pergunta, e sim um link pra central de ajuda.